# Can I build a Model for two Tables on PhalconPHP?

Tags: mysql, phalcon

I have one `games` table and two tables to store their scores, `game_scores` and `thirdparty_game_scores` with exactly the same structure, something like that:

```
-------------------------GAMES-------------------------
slug | title | technology | (other non-relevant fields)
-------------------------------------------------------

----------------------GAME SCORES----------------------
 id (PK) | game_slug | user | team | score | timestamp
-------------------------------------------------------

----------------THIRDPARTY GAME SCORES-----------------
 id (PK) | game_slug | user | team | score | timestamp
-------------------------------------------------------
```

And their Models like:

```
class GameScores extends BaseGamesModel {

  public function initialize() {
    parent::initialize();
    $this->belongsTo( 'game_slug', 'Games', 'slug' );
    $this->skipAttributes(array('creation_time', 'last_modified'));
  }
}
```

I'm building a weekly ranking with game scores stored only on `game_scores`:

```
$ranking = GameScores::sum(
  array(
    "column" => "score",
    "conditions" => $conditions,
    "group" => "team",
    "order" => "sumatory DESC"
  )
);
```

Is there any way to create a Model that concatenates all data from `game_scores` and `thirdparty_game_scores` to create the same ranking without any extra effort?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Remove table `thirdparty_game_scores`. Use one table `game_scores` and add column `thirdparty` (yes/no) to this table.

Comment: Thanks @Phantom :) That's an obvious (and surely the best) solution for this situation, but it's not my decision to alter the database. I was asking to figure out other possibilities...

Comment: Do you have the ability to push for that decision? Because thats an awful schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the source table dynamically in your model. See [Can I build a Model for two Tables on PhalconPHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806202/can-i-build-a-model-for-two-tables-on-phalconphp)

You should use the setSource() method and put your condition in there, e.g.:

```
   $source = 'default_table';
   if (class_name($this) === 'A') {
      $source = 'A_table'; 
   }
   return $source;
```